# ¿Cómo crear datos si no existe y modificar si ya existe?

Tags: python, django

Estoy buscando la manera de que cuando la base de datos esté vacía cree un objecto para llenar una fila y cuando exista uno modificarlo.

Este es el código:

```
def AnalizarAction(action, reporte):
    w = action.split(' ')
    if 'change' in action:
        estado = w[-1]
    elif 'assigned' in action:
        estado = w[-1]
    else:
        estado = '%s %s' % (w[-2], w[-1])
    estado = estado.replace("'", "")


    try:
        resultado = Mostrar_Resultado.objects.get(nombre=reporte.user)        
        alm_asignadar = resultado.alarma_asignada+1
        datos_devueltos = getParametrosByEstado(alm_asignadar,reporte, estado)
        # Solo se modifica
        if type(datos_devueltos) == dict:

            resultado.alarma_asignada = alm_asignadar,            
            resultado.fraude = datos_devueltos['fraude'],            
            resultado.no_fraude = datos_devueltos['no_fraude'],            
            resultado.disponible_fr = datos_devueltos['disponible_fra'],
            resultado.alm_inv = datos_devueltos['alm_inv'],            
            resultado.bajo_inv_cierre = datos_devueltos['bajo_inv_cierre'],
            resultado.por_ciento_fr = datos_devueltos['por_ciento_fr'],
            resultado.uso_sistema = datos_devueltos['uso_sistema']
            resultado.save()

    except Mostrar_Resultado.DoesNotExist:
        alm_asignadar = 1
        datos_devueltos = getParametrosByEstado(alm_asignadar, reporte, estado)

        if type(datos_devueltos) == dict:
            fraude = datos_devueltos['fraude']
            no_fraude = datos_devueltos['no_fraude']
            disponible_fra = datos_devueltos['disponible_fra']
            alm_inv = datos_devueltos['alm_inv']
            bajo_inv_cierre = datos_devueltos['bajo_inv_cierre']
            por_ciento_fr = datos_devueltos['por_ciento_fr']
            uso_sistema = datos_devueltos['uso_sistema']
            llaver = reporte
            nombrer = reporte.user
            fechar = reporte.day
            CrearResultado(llaver, nombrer, fechar, alm_asignadar, fraude, no_fraude, disponible_fra, alm_inv,
                       bajo_inv_cierre, por_ciento_fr, uso_sistema)
```

Comment: Una duda que no salgo de ella como formular la pregunta donde el codigo no este con el texto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es la función [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create). Por lo que algo como esto:

```
try:
    obj = Person.objects.get(first_name='Cesar', last_name='Bustios')
    obj.age = 31
    obj.save()
except Person.DoesNotExist:        
    obj = Person()
    obj.first_name = 'Cesar'
    obj.last_name = 'Bustios'
    obj.age = 31
    obj.save()
```

Ahora, lo puedes hacer así:

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
    first_name='Cesar', 
    last_name='Bustios', 
    defaults={'age': 31}
)
```

Lo que está haciendo la función `update_or_create` es buscar un objeto con todos los parámetros que estén antes de `defaults`, es decir, está usando `first_name` y `last_name` para buscar el registro. Y usa todo lo que esté en `defaults` para actualizarlo si es que lo encuentra.

La función retorna dos cosas: el objeto, y un booleano que indica si el registro ha sido creado o no, por lo tanto es posible que puedes hacer otras operaciones consultando el booleano:

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
    first_name='Cesar', 
    last_name='Bustios', 
    defaults={'age': 31}
)

if created:
    # Se ha creado un registro, hacer algo más por aquí
```

También te gustaría darle una ojeada a [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create).